# EMF references cannot be resolved with binary resources

Tags: java, eclipse, emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

I have the following EMF structure and the problem is when I persist the EMF-Model with a binary resource, I cannot load it afterwards completely because the references between the `ServiceOperationNode` and the `ServiceOperation` cannot be resolved.
The strange thing is when I use a XMI resource everything works fine, but because out of performance reasons and storage requirements we are forced to use binary files.
[image]

```
// first I set-up my resource registry
Resource.Factory.Registry reg = Resource.Factory.Registry.INSTANCE;
reg.getExtensionToFactoryMap().put("bin", new Resource.Factory() {
  @Override
  public Resource createResource(final URI uri) {
     return new BinaryResourceImpl(uri);
  }
});

this.resourceSet = new ResourceSetImpl();

// then I create two resources
Resource resource1 = this.resourceSet.createResource(filePath1);
Resource resource2 = this.resourceSet.createResource(filePath2);

// and add all my objects to each resource
resource1.getContents().add(...);
resource2.getContents().add(...);

// after that I save the resources
resource1.save(ResourceAdder.createOptions());
resource2.save(ResourceAdder.createOptions());
```

One other thing I noticed was that when I add the `ServiceOperation` to the first resource I can resolve the reference between `ServiceOperationNode` and `ServiceOperation` but then the other reference from the `Service` doesn't work anymore ...

Any ideas or pointers are welcome!

Comment: Is the reference from ServiceOperationNode to ServiceOperation a containment reference? How about from Service to ServiceOperation? Any EObject can only be contained once.

Comment: No none of the references is a containment reference ...

Comment: Ok. As you said, the XMI resource works. Hmmm...

Comment: Wait. Your "one other thing ... when I add the `ServiceOperation` to the first resource ...". The diagram shows the `ServiceOperation` in the second resource. Why would you add it to the first resource?

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom I just did that for testing purposes because I wanted to know if the behaviour changes when I add it to a different resource and yeah it did ...

Comment: And you're not seeing any exceptions thrown? Nothing in the eclipse log?

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom No there are no exception but I found out that the eStorage of `ServiceOperationNode` is null ... Whatever reason could that be ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84208/discussion-between-erick-g-hagstrom-and-tom1991te).